# https:// domain .com redirecting to https:// www

Tags: apache, nginx, configuration

My nginx config is mostly working with https, all redirects from http to https are working except from https://example.com which needs redirect to https://www.example.com Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I've tried adding the redirect in the server block listening to 443 for example.com to redirect to www.example.com but I had the same issue.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/qc/public;

    error_log  /var/www/qc/error.log debug;
    access_log /var/www/qc/access.log;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt$
            root /usr/share/;
        }
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # m$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; #$
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # m$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; #$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I'd like the url https://example.com to redirect to https://www.example.com

Comment: This will create a loop: `if ($host = example.com) { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example.com bracket, you don't need the "if ($host = example.com) {"
as you already delimit the hosts that enter this bracket by setting "server_name example.com;" . Also when you redirect to https://$host$request_uri; , you are redirecting to example.com, not to www.example.com, creating an infinite loop of redirections.

Hops this helps, this is the example.com config that should work:

```
server {

 location / {

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }

    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # m$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; #$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the if block with
`return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot`
and it worked